# How to make a persistent background task signal a scoped service in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2

In my ASP.NET Core 2.2 web application I have these scoped services in my Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDirectoryBrowser();

    services.AddScoped<WebApplication.Services.DoThingAlpha>();
    services.AddScoped<WebApplication.Services.DoThingBravo>();
    services.AddScoped<WebApplication.Services.DoThingCharlie>();

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

These scoped services do the dirty work for my controllers.

However, I have a need to constantly listen on a UDP port in the background and then notify the appropriate service (DoThingsAlpha, DoThingsBravo, or DoThingsCharlie) when certain UDP messages are received on the listener.

I think I can implement the background service with BackgroundService (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice) and then add to the services collection in ConfigureServices. Lets call it ListenOnUDP : BackgroundService

The rub is, how do I go about signaling to those other scoped services that the UDP message was received in ListenOnUDP? What is the recommended pattern to solve this kind of problem? Surely there is one.

Comment: Are you saying that the scoped services need to be able to block until a certain datagram is received? Or do you mean that the services simply need to be aware of the most recent datagram, e.g. when it was received and what was in it?

Comment: The same as the one you already use - use DI to register a "notification" interface that the scoped services depend on. That interface will be implemented by the background service directly or better yet, a "notifier" object created by that service. That `notifier` interface in turn could provide notifications as callbacks, or TaskCompletionSource-based tasks

Comment: @JohnWu the scoped services need to block (wait) for 1 second or so, and then give up if there is no datagram received. If a second has passed, we can assume it's never going to come in.

Comment: @TimothyJohnLaird instead of blocking, they can *await* a task produced by a taskcompletionsource controlled by the background service

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as long as there is a cancellation if more than one second has elapsed I think so. To explain my use case... the scoped service currently uses await UdpClient.Sendasync to command another process (that is listening) to do something. I need to add some logic (somehow) to recieve a UDP ack and then return back to the controller that either no ACK was recieved or an ACK was recieved.

Comment: Why not return the signal over UDP to the client that sent the message to begin with? If the client is the same scoped service, that would meet the requirement, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JohnWu so we are on the same page...
HTTP request from browser => Controller => Scoped Service => Udp Client to Different Process => Udp Client in Other process ACKS back => Scoped service recieves a notification of the ACK (somehow???) => Controller responds to user "command received" => HTTP response to browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have worked out a solution and I think the problem stemmed from my fundamental lack of understanding of ASP.NET Core services. I will explain in case someone has the same issue (or perhaps validate or invalidate my answer).

When you add a service class/interface to your IServiceCollection that service becomes accessible to other services via the interface. You simply include the interface in the constructor of the other service you want to call in your constructor, save it and you can then call the interface (what I take to understand is a manifestation of dependency injection). Like so:

```
    private readonly InterfaceRCResponseQueue _rcResponseQueue;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public UdpListenerBackgroundService(
        InterfaceRCResponseQueue rcResponseQueue,
        ILogger<UdpListenerBackgroundService> logger
        )
    {
        _rcResponseQueue = rcResponseQueue;
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

This, effectively lets one service signal another by calling methods on the interface.

The catch:

A singleton service cannot be dependent on a scoped or transient service. Presumably because it hangs up the scoped or transient service. The reverse is OK though.

https://blog.markvincze.com/two-gotchas-with-scoped-and-singleton-dependencies-in-asp-net-core/

In my case, I have a UdpClient class that needs to listen for messages and then signal other services.

To do so, I put my UdpClient class in class that inherits from Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService and therefore gets created and torn down with the life of the application. I also created a singleton class that holds a queue.

When my UdpClient class in my BackgroundService class gets a UDP datagram, I call a method on the singleton class that enqueues it in the singleton class' queue.

A scoped, singleton or transient class can then depend on the singleton class and look for data in that queue (dequeue) at it's leisure. You just can't do the reverse (make a singleton depend on a scoped or transitive service).

That is the form of signalling I came up with, to indirectly notify a lesser service from a singleton or background service.

Comment: Thanks for your writeup, it helped push me in the right direction. I was using BackgroundService and then wondering why my scoped services were acting as singletons. I ended up going with IServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope to create new scopes when my message handler had some more work to do. Seems to be working well.